# Write a query to print all prime numbers less than or equal to

Tags: sql

> Write a query to print all prime numbers less than or equal to. Print your result on a single line, and use the ampersand (&) character as your separator (instead of a space).

> For example, the output for all prime numbers (<= 10) would be:

> Output : 2&3&5&7

Comment: Is this homework? Pick an RDBMS, because they're all different.

Comment: Who prints any more?  Why not FAX the list?

Comment: You query would consist of: recursive common table expression (RCTE) to generate a table of numbers from 1 to 10, self left join it to get all divisors (from 2 to current - 1) of current number, grouping the result by this current, calculation of division modulo. The result should be aggregated with something like listagg function. Try to implement it on your own and show the result.

Answer (score 1):

Different RDBMS have their own syntax / functions for RCTE and string aggregation.
Below is an example for [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9b78f7aa2c5c6c44d855424a7198ce14):

```
WITH RECURSIVE T (I) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT I+1 FROM T WHERE I < 10)
SELECT STRING_AGG (I::TEXT, '&') AS LST
FROM
(
  SELECT A.I 
  FROM T A
  LEFT JOIN T B ON B.I BETWEEN 2 AND A.I - 1
  -- Actually, 1 is prime as well...
  WHERE A.I > 1
  GROUP BY A.I
  HAVING COUNT (CASE MOD (A.I, B.I) WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
  ORDER BY A.I
) A
```

| LST |
| --- |
| 2&3&5&7 |

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided below might be of assistance.
**MSSQL**

```
DECLARE @n INT = 1000;
DECLARE @x INT = 2;
DECLARE @z INT;
DECLARE @temp TABLE (A INT)

WHILE (@x <= @n)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @temp
    SELECT @x

    SET @z = 2

    WHILE (@z < @x)
    BEGIN
        IF (@x % @z <> 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @z = @z + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            DELETE
            FROM @temp
            WHERE A = @x

            BREAK
        END
    END

    SET @x = @x + 1
END;

SELECT STRING_AGG(A, '&')
FROM @temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for MS SQL

```
declare @upperlimit int = 1000; --represents the maximum number to which we want prime numbers
declare @currentnumber int = 2; --will be used as an iterator to check each number from 2 up to @upperLimit for primality
declare @divisor int; --will be used in the inner loop to check if a number is divisible by any other number
declare @primenumbers table (numbers int); --create a table variable called @primeNumbers to store the prime numbers with a single column 'number' of type INT
--loop that iterates from @currentNumber (initially 2) up to @upperLimit
while (@currentnumber <= @upperlimit)
begin
    insert into @primenumbers --Insert @currentNumber into the @primeNumbers table since @currentNumber is a potential prime number
    select @currentnumber
    set @divisor = 2 --start checking divisibility from 2
    while (@divisor < @currentnumber)
--an inner WHILE loop that checks if @currentNumber is divisible by any number from 2 to @currentNumber 
    begin 
        if(@currentnumber % @divisor <> 0)
        begin
            set @divisor = @divisor + 1
/*
If @currentNumber is not divisible by @divisor, we increment @divisor by 1 and continue checking the next number;If @currentNumber is divisible by @divisor, we delete @currentNumber from the @primeNumbers table since it is not a prime number. We then break out of the inner loop using BREAK
*/
        end
        else
        begin
            delete from @primenumbers where numbers  = @currentnumber
            break
        end
    end
    set @currentnumber = @currentnumber + 1 --After the inner loop finishes, we increment @currentNumber by 1 to move on to the next number
end
select string_agg(numbers,'&') from @primenumbers  

/*
Once the outer WHILE loop completes and all numbers from 2 to @upperLimit have been checked, the @primeNumbers table will contain only prime numbers. Finally, we use the STRING_AGG function to concatenate the prime numbers in the Number column of the @primeNumbers table, separating them with the ampersand (&) character. The result is returned as a single string.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @upperlimit int = 1000;
declare @currentnumber int = 2;
declare @divisor int;
declare @primenumber table(numbers int);

while(@currentnumber < @upperlimit)
begin 

insert into @primenumber
select @currentnumber
select @divisor = 2
while (@divisor < @currentnumber)
begin
    if(@currentnumber % @divisor <> 0)
    begin
        set @divisor = @divisor + 1
    end
    else
    begin
        delete from @primenumber where numbers = @currentnumber
        break
    end
end
set @currentnumber = @currentnumber + 1
```

end

select string_agg(numbers,'&') from @primenumber

Comment: Please provide more context in your answer so that it has more than just the code. Consider including explanation of where this should be put, or why it works better.

Comment: The code in your answer appears to be identical to the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73453046/write-a-query-to-print-all-prime-numbers-less-than-or-equal-to/76540181#76540181). Can you explain how your answer is different to that one? Does your answer provide anything that does **not** appear in the other answers?